# Scraping URLs with Python Arrays

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to put URLs into an array, so I can use them again. But when I change the array index of 0 to 1, my compiler says "IndexError: list index out of range".

Why are the URLs being stored in only index 0?

Thanks

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode, urlparse, parse_qs

from lxml.html import fromstring
from requests import get
raw = get("https://www.google.com/search?q=StackOverflow").text
page = fromstring(raw)

for result in page.cssselect(".r a"):
    url = result.get("href")
    if url.startswith("/url?"):
        url = parse_qs(urlparse(url).query)['q']
        print(url[1])
```

Comment: That means there only one item in list `url`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a list to collect each of the urls you find:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode, urlparse, parse_qs
from lxml.html import fromstring
from requests import get

raw = get("https://www.google.com/search?q=StackOverflow").text
page = fromstring(raw)

# an empty list of the urls
urls = []

for result in page.cssselect(".r a"):
    url = result.get("href")
    if url.startswith("/url?"):
        url = parse_qs(urlparse(url).query)['q']
        # add this url to the list of urls
        urls += url

print(urls)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python is zero base so you need to do this

`print(url[0])`

or better yet

`print(url)`